# I have imported my database from previous website and now it is not showing up on new site? Lost and Confused

Tags: wordpress, server-migration

I have imported my database from previous website and now it is not showing up on new site? Lost and Confused, need help understanding why if someone is out there...I can see the data in database imported.

Comment: Many people who migrate WordPress installations from server to server use  plugins like Duplicator to avoid all the mucking around that's needed when doing it manually.

Comment: Does any error shows up, After turning on error on wp-config.php

Answer (score 1):

If you did not lose the old copy I strongly advise you to migrate your database using migration tools:
I see you tagged your question with `wordpress` tag so I can tell you there are plenty of plugins to do that, like:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Specifically to migrate the DB only there is

https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/

Comment: I see it on the back end but its not showing on the front , weird

Comment: Yes It actually migrated with the help of all in one migration, but now im constantly getting errors after activating buddypress, So I wonder whats the server  Error 500

Comment: as additional resource I attach this link : https://neliosoftware.com/blog/wordpress-migration-problems-and-how-to-fix-them/